# TCP available congestion control - reno or new reno?

Tags: networking, 20.04, kernel, tcp-ip

I use Ubuntu 20.04.

`sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_available_congestion_control`

returns:

`net.ipv4.tcp_available_congestion_control = reno cubic`

I am not sure whether reno is in fact new-reno.
I see fast transmits of the loss packets in wireshark, and there is past tcp man that says that new-reno was the default cc before cubic.
I tried to find the code for it on https://elixir.bootlin.com but failed to get answer there.

`ls -la /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/ipv4` do not show any of them

Is reno actually new-reno? and if not, is it possible to select new-reno?

Information about where I can find both will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant file in the kernel source tree is `net/ipv4/tcp_cong.c`and the header is:

```
/ SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-only
/*
 * Pluggable TCP congestion control support and newReno
 * congestion control.
 * Based on ideas from I/O scheduler support and Web100.
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2005 Stephen Hemminger <shemminger@osdl.org>
 */
```

Further down the file:

```
/*
 * TCP Reno congestion control
 * This is special case used for fallback as well.
 */
/* This is Jacobson's slow start and congestion avoidance.
 * SIGCOMM '88, p. 328.
 */
```

It is the only congestion control algorithm that has no kernel configuration switch, it is always built in. cubic shows as available because in Ubuntu the kernel configuration is set to include it, built-in. The rest of the possible control algorithms are modules. The relevant section of the kernel configuration:

```
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_BIC=m
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_CUBIC=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_WESTWOOD=m
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_HTCP=m
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_HSTCP=m
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_HYBLA=m
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_VEGAS=m
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_NV=m
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_SCALABLE=m
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_LP=m
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_VENO=m
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_YEAH=m
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_ILLINOIS=m
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_DCTCP=m
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_CDG=m
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_BBR=m
CONFIG_DEFAULT_CUBIC=y
# CONFIG_DEFAULT_RENO is not set
CONFIG_DEFAULT_TCP_CONG="cubic"
```

So by default one gets (as you did):

```
doug@s19:~/kernel/linux$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_available_congestion_control
reno cubic
```

But once the modules are loaded, one gets:

```
doug@s19:~/kernel/linux$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_available_congestion_control
reno cubic bic westwood htcp highspeed hybla vegas veno lp nv scalable yeah illinois dctcp cdg bbr
```